# github: code review without pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Using a [shared repository model](https://help.github.com/articles/about-collaborative-development-models/). In short:

- we want to be able to review code changes
- but, we don't want pull requests to hold up integration at all

I've used a workflow like this in the past with Code Collaborator, but I don't think it was with Git(?).  The point is to allow quicker code integration, while at the same time providing some review of code changes.  If the review finds issues, the developer just fixes the issues and integrates, updating the code review in the process.  Once the code review is done, there's no "pull" (merge): the code is already merged; the review just gets closed.

Comment: If you need real code review, there is always a ref waiting to be merged, either in the local repository or in the remote repository. Only after the new commits are proved, the ref is allowed to be merged into the target branch.  The point of code review is to improve the quality of the code. If merge comes before review, there could be many bad commits in the history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still can [consider Gerrit](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/intro-quick.html) for your review process.
It even has an "[auto-merge during Push](https://dev.vaadin.com/review/Documentation/user-upload.html#auto_merge)" which would allow you to merge immediately, while retaining a spot where to conduct your review.

As commented, this is not the ideal workflow, but the point is: you can configure [Gerrit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit) in multiple ways.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.  I'll only comment that I think "the ideal workflow" is entirely contextual -- different workflows are ideal for different situations.

Comment: @HawkeyeParker you are right, I didn't mean to imply there is only one "true" workflow indeed.