# Do a code review on a whole project without a pull request

Tags: git, review

I am teaching programming and I would like to review/comment my student's code.

The easy way to do it would be to create a pull request, but when students are beginners, they are not familiar with branches, and so it's not that easy for them.

There are already questions like that but they don't have answers and are a bit different, for ex [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984668/github-code-review-without-pull-request) is about reviewing *changes* and not a a whole project.

I would preferably like a solution using Github, which I think at the moment is not possible [as it is an open issue](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/284), but I am open to hacky solution, or other tools. The important is just the ability to comment code by line.

The solution I am looking for needs to:

- Allow adding comments on every line of all the files of one branch or master
- Not require pull request
- Not require comparing branches
- Not require installing another software than Git

Comment: Which tools have to looked at? As you've asked now - your question is off-topic for SO, you're seeking 'recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources'.

Comment: "*Not require pull request*" Yeah, but since they're dealing with code and learning programming, maybe it's a good idea that they also learn basic version control, creating branches, and submitting PR's (or merge request on some other platforms).

Comment: I heard about Gerrit or Crucible for example, but the tools I found were either time consuming to configure, or require to install a software, which I am not willing to do. I asked the question here because I think there could be a functionnality of Github I am not aware of that could solve my problem.

Comment: Anyway, maybe something like Atlassian's Crucible is what you need (see [What's the difference between Crucible and Bitbucket Server?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/what-s-the-difference-between-crucible-and-bitbucket-server-do-i-need-both-779171640.html)). I remember you still need to setup a repository of sorts and point Crucible to it, but it does support reviewing branches, files, patches not in a PR and commenting on lines.

Comment: @GinoMempin There's a time for everything, for some people it's difficult to learn all these things at once, and my work as teacher is to make it as accessible as possible. Thanks for the recommendation of Crucible, eventhough I am not willing to install a software. I edited my question to reflect that!

Answer (score 5):

Using Github and a single branch as you stipulate you could create issues for each of your comments, linking them to the lines or blocks of code in question. You can do this by highlighting the code and copying the updated url to a created issue or using the dropdown to `Reference in new issue`. This keeps the code un-altered and can all be done/viewed in the github web interface.

[image]

You can create different issue labels to indicate the severity of the comment/issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great idea! It's a bit overwhelming if one needs to add lots of comments, as issues are longer to post/edit than comments. But it works, thanks!